# $r$ balls are randomly distributed into $n$ urns. What's the expected number of urns with $k$ balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My text book uses the linearity of the expected value to compute it. It defines a random variable $X_i$ that indicates whether the urn $i$ contains $k$ balls or not. So the asked value is $E[X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n]$.

What is not entirely clear for me is the following. It states that $P\{X_i=1\}={r \choose k}({{1}\over{n}})^k({1-{{1}\over{n}}})^{r-k}$. However, if the balls are indistinguishable, I thought we should compute that probability with the "stars and bars" approach?

Comment: Whether they are distinguishable or not does not affect the probability. Imagine that the balls have distinct ID numbers writtten in invisible ink.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Somehow I got confused by the answers to [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106860/if-n-balls-are-distributed-randomly-into-k-urns-what-is-the-probability-tha] (this question) where the probability changes depending whether balls are distinguishable or not.

Comment: Depends on the probability model. If the balls are thrown at the urns one at a time independently, the answer is as in your post, distinguishable or not. Note that the patterns counted by Stars and Bars are not all equally likely under that model. I cannot evaluate the question you referred to, since it does not state the problem in a precise way. Maybe there was a link that disappeared.